# Данные с формы не передаются в контроллер

Tags: java, spring

При заполнении всех данных формы на jsp странице и отправки их, получаю ошибку

> Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of
> "com.boots.entity.User.getPassword()" is null

В чем может быть проблема?

контроллер

```
@PostMapping("/registration")
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") @Valid User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }
    if (!userForm.getPassword().equals(userForm.getPasswordConfirm())){
        model.addAttribute("passwordError", "Пароли не совпадают");
        return "registration";
    }
    if (!userService.saveUser(userForm)){
        model.addAttribute("usernameError", "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует");
        return "registration";
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

registration.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <%--@elvariable id="userForm" type=""--%>
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm">
        <h2>Регистрация</h2>
        <div>
            <form:input type="text" path="username" placeholder="Username"
                        autofocus="true"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="username"></form:errors>
                ${usernameError}
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:input type="password" path="password" placeholder="Password"></form:input>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:input type="password" path="passwordConfirm"
                        placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
                ${passwordError}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form:form>
    <a href="/">Главная</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Size(min=2, message = "Не меньше 5 знаков")
    private String username;
    @Size(min=2, message = "Не меньше 5 знаков")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;
    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

введите сюда код

введите сюда код
```

Comment: все те же лица) я гляну сегодня вечером, если никто до этого времени не напишет ответ

Comment: что-то тут не сходится. у меня не получается воспроизвести.

Comment: валидация срабатывает правильно?